# Responsive Bootstrap Button according to screen sizes

Tags: css, angular, responsive-design, bootstrap-5

I would like this button to be responsive, automatically adjusting its size to fit various screen dimensions. In this following code button is fixed and not moving.
Here is the code.

```
<button type="button" [className]="'btn btn-block m-0'" kendoButton id="btnLogin1" *ngIf="!opened"
        (click)="open()">Login</button>
```

CSS Code:

```
#btnLogin1 {
  background-color: #0057b8;
  border: 1px solid #0057B8;
  color: #fff !important;
  height: 35px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: large;
  margin: 35px 0 0;
  padding: 25px 100px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with using media queries. As shown in following code.

```css
#btnLogin1 {
  background-color: #0057b8;
  border: 1px solid #0057B8;
  color: #fff !important;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  font-size: large;
  margin: 35px 0 0;
  padding: 25px 100px;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #btnLogin1 {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  padding: 25px 50px;
}
}
```

```html
<button type="button" [className]="'btn btn-block m-0'" kendoButton id="btnLogin1" *ngIf="!opened"
        (click)="open()">Login</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vmin` or `vmax` units.
If you don't want to use media query find a perfect value that works for you.
For reference how they work check out this blog: [CSS Units](https://dev.to/matthias/units-in-css-em-rem-pt-px-vw-vh-vmin-vmax-ex-ch-53l0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).